# Off Canvas Navigation Default Open/Closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an off canvas navigation on a website that I am working on. The default state for the off canvas navigation is closed which works well on the mobile site as you can toggle it open and select your links but on the desktop having it closed and toggling it on hides information from the user and I would like it to be open by default when the user arrives at the page.

Currently the navigation uses jQuery to make the toggle:

```
$( "#main-menu-toggle, #main-menu-caption, .menu-mask" ).on( "click", function() {
    // toggle the classes in the body the css does the rest
    $( "body" ).toggleClass( 'main-menu-open' );

    // for screen readers lets set the ARIA atributes
    if ( $( "body" ).hasClass( 'main-menu-open' ) ) {
        $( '#navbar, #main-menu-toggle' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
    } else {
        $( '#navbar, #main-menu-toggle' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
    }
});
```

And there is a call in there when the page loads as well as resizes to show and hide the menu depending on screen size:

```
// show or hide the main navigation menu when the page is loaded
showHideMenu();

$( window ).resize(function() {
    waitForDraggingStop(function(){
        showHideMenu();
    }, 500, "window resize in progress");
});

// adds or removes the classes for the menu addition or removal
function showHideMenu() {
    if ( 955 < $( window ).width() ) {
        $( "body" ).addClass( 'main-menu-open' );
        $( '#navbar, #main-menu-toggle' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );      
    } else {
        $( "body" ).removeClass( 'main-menu-open' );
        $( '#navbar, #main-menu-toggle' ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );     
    }
}
```

The issue is that the menu has an animation associated with it and so when you arrive on the desktop there is a delay and then the menu animates out. This quickly becomes annoying to the user as they have to wait for the page to finish its animations before they can use the screen.

**The Question:** 
Is there a better way to do this using the CSS/JS that will have the menu expanded by default when the user comes to the page above 955px and collapsed by default below the same mark AND allow for the direction to be reversed on the click of the toggle later on and avoid the delays associated with animation using JS to add the open class?

Comment: I had a thought here that if i treated the jQuery added class like a status toggle instead of a state i may be able to retool the css in order to get what i want. 

Above 955 the css would default to open in the absence of the toggle but its presence would close it and below 955 the absence would keep it closed but its presence would open it. This would completely remove the jQuery adding the class on load as well as the resize function. 

would probably be better to rename the body class to something like "main-menu-open-close"

Comment: This is very easy... you should be using media queries for this... not js.  So... mobile first...  menu is off-canvas using positioning or translateX....  at 955px wide, you then change the positioning or translateX.  Very simple.

Comment: @SeanStopnik Correct that is how it is working but it needs to be able to open and close via a toggle with different default states depending on screen size. 955 or > is default open and the toggle closes it < 955 default is closed and the toggle opens it. I ended up solving it using the method from the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using the method from my comments:

I treated the jQuery added class like a status toggle instead of a state like open or closed.

Above 955 the css would default to open in the absence of the toggle but its presence would close it and below 955 the absence would keep it closed but its presence would open it.

This would completely remove the jQuery adding the class on load as well as the resize function.

Additionally I renamed the body class to "main-menu-open-close" to reflect the toggle.